# Meaning of Julia error: ERROR (unhandled task failure): EOFError: read end of file?

Tags: julia

Trying to understand following error in a `pmap` execution of some embarrassingly parallel tasks. Running on Linux server. *might* be occurring while writing to HDF (part of parallel call), but I don't think so given stacktrace doesn't point to line in the user-function being executed, and reference to TCP suggests it's part of parallel calls. Has happened in several sequential runs, so not one-time fluke.

```
Worker 139 terminated.
ERROR (unhandled task failure): EOFError: read end of file
Stacktrace:
 [1] unsafe_read(::Base.AbstractIOBuffer{Array{UInt8,1}}, ::Ptr{UInt8}, ::UInt64) at ./iobuffer.jl:105
 [2] unsafe_read(::TCPSocket, ::Ptr{UInt8}, ::UInt64) at ./stream.jl:752
 [3] unsafe_read(::TCPSocket, ::Base.RefValue{NTuple{4,Int64}}, ::Int64) at ./io.jl:361
 [4] read at ./io.jl:363 [inlined]
 [5] deserialize_hdr_raw at ./distributed/messages.jl:170 [inlined]
 [6] message_handler_loop(::TCPSocket, ::TCPSocket, ::Bool) at ./distributed/process_messages.jl:157
 [7] process_tcp_streams(::TCPSocket, ::TCPSocket, ::Bool) at ./distributed/process_messages.jl:118
 [8] (::Base.Distributed.##99#100{TCPSocket,TCPSocket,Bool})() at ./event.jl:73
```

Julia info:

```
julia> versioninfo()

Julia Version 0.6.0
Commit 9036443 (2017-06-19 13:05 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Linux (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
  CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5620  @ 2.40GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Nehalem)
  LAPACK: libopenblas64_
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.9.1 (ORCJIT, westmere)
```

[EDIT: more info] Also, if it's helpful, this appears to be happening well into the run -- output from the first set of parallel runs looks like it's being saved to disk, so this is not an immediate crash, but something that's happening at the end of a run or start of the second set of executions.

Comment: Maybe a memory leak? It is difficult to say anything more without some example code that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, so I did finally figure out at a high level what this means:

This is the error you get when one of the parallelized workers hits an error. The specific error language (`EOFError: read end of file`) doesn't really mean anything. And the references to `read` and `io` in the stackoverflow just relate to messaging between the overview task and workers.

In my case, the error was a memory overflow leading to the task manager terminating the worker.